# Numpy to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a numpy array that looks like this:

```
data = [{'DateTime': '2020-03-13T16:44:58-03:00', 'Hl': 81.5, 'Bl': 82.5}, 
        {'DateTime': '2020-03-13T16:44:58-03:00', 'Hl': 87.7, 'Bl': 2.94}]
```

I want this to a pandas DataFrame that looks like

```
Index                 DataTime     Hl   Bl
1    2020-03-13T16:44:58-03:00   81.5 82.5
2    2020-03-13T16:44:58-03:00   87.7 2.94
```

The column names need to be generated from what is in the numpy array as they vary from array to array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert list of dictionaries to a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also use

`import pandas as pd`

`data = [{'DateTime': '2020-03-13T16:44:58-03:00', 'Hl': 81.5, 'Bl': 82.5},{'DateTime': '2020-03-13T16:44:58-03:00', 'Hl': 87.7, 'Bl': 2.94}]`

`df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)`

these `pandas.DataFrame.from_records` and `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict` functions from pandas can be useful for you.

Comment: In my case the dictionary was not formatted correctly and the pandas.DataFrame.from_records fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you were very nearly there. Just send your `data` array to the DataFrame constructor.

The DataFrame constructor can read a `dict` (or list of dicts, in this case) and uses the key/value pairs as columns/values, respectively. This means the column names will be dynamic as required, based on the keys of the `dict`.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'DateTime': '2020-03-13T16:44:58-03:00', 'Hl': 81.5, 'Bl': 82.5},
        {'DateTime': '2020-03-13T16:44:58-03:00', 'Hl': 87.7, 'Bl': 2.94}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output:

```
                    DateTime    Hl     Bl
0  2020-03-13T16:44:58-03:00  81.5  82.50
1  2020-03-13T16:44:58-03:00  87.7   2.94
```