# How to convert dictionaries having same keys in multiple rows to a dataframe

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionaries stored in the below format

```
0     {'neg': 0.013, 'neu': 0.783, 'pos': 0.205, 'co...
1     {'neg': 0.072, 'neu': 0.68, 'pos': 0.248, 'com...
2     {'neg': 0.017, 'neu': 0.721, 'pos': 0.262, 'co...
3     {'neg': 0.03, 'neu': 0.783, 'pos': 0.187, 'com...
4     {'neg': 0.029, 'neu': 0.683, 'pos': 0.288, 'co...
```

I want to convert these into a dataframe with keys (neg, neu, pos, com) as columns and the values as rows of each index:

```
neg   neu   pos   com
.013  .783  .205  .456
.072  .68   .248  .456
......................
......................
```

The pattern should be as above. I tried hard but was not able to figure out. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert list of dictionaries to a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Are the keys always the same in each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_name)
```

You can also try another

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(dict_name)
```

Comment: pd.DataFrame.from_records(dict_name) . This solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the pandas library to perform this task. But first you need to combine all your dictionaries into one dictionary by doing:

```
dict1.update(dict2)# do this for all dicts
```

After running the above line, dict1 and dict2 will be save in dict1.

After that, you can turn your final dict into a pandas data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
myDataFrame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1)
```

Comment: dict.update() overwrites existing keys, so you will lose all data from later dicts if they all contain the same keys, as indicated in the original question. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update