# Trying to convert list of dictionaries to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

I am trying to convert a list of dictionaries to a pandas dataframe like in the stackoverflow post here, however for whatever reason I cant get it to work.

[Convert list of dictionaries to a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-pandas-dataframe)

When I try to do it with my code below, I get a 1824 rows × 1 columns data object, which is not correct (I want 6 columns).

Here is a snapshot of my data object (returned from response.text) which I want in my pandas DataFrame

```
[
{
    "base_attack": 118,
    "base_defense": 111,
    "base_stamina": 128,
    "form": "Fall_2019",
    "pokemon_id": 1,
    "pokemon_name": "Bulbasaur"
},
{
    "base_attack": 118,
    "base_defense": 111,
    "base_stamina": 128,
    "form": "Normal",
    "pokemon_id": 1,
    "pokemon_name": "Bulbasaur"
},
]
```

Here is my code (api key is public and used in examples):

```
import requests

url = "https://pokemon-go1.p.rapidapi.com/pokemon_stats.json"

headers = {
 'x-rapidapi-key': "4a84fad910msha335a71778de51cp1a79d6jsnafac3cffa115",
 'x-rapidapi-host': "pokemon-go1.p.rapidapi.com"
 }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)

df = pd.DataFrame(response)

df
```

I have also tried these 2 approached:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k: v for d in response.text for k, v in d.items()}, 
                         orient='index', 
                         columns=['pokemon_name', 'form', 'base_attack', 'base_defense', 
                         'base_stamina']).rename_axis('pokemon_id').reset_index()

df = pd.DataFrame(response.text, columns=['base_attack', 'base_defense', 'base_stamina', 
                                'form', 'pokemon_id', 'pokemon_name'])
```

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(response.json())`

Comment: I cannot access the API, as the creds are blocked. But I suspect based on what you have, is that the api is returning a string version of json. Thus you could just use Json.loads(response.text) and pass that to pd.DataFrame and it should work. But Pandas does allow for you to create a DataFrame directly from pd.DataFrame() and a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Your first solution worked for me. I'm using  pandas version 0.22.0 (use this command to check yours: pd.__version__) on python 3.6.10

Answer (score 1):

Your `response.text` is a string, not a dictionary as Pandas expects. You should use `response.json()` if that's available.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(response.json(), columns=['base_attack', 'base_defense', 'base_stamina', 
                                'form', 'pokemon_id', 'pokemon_name'])
```

---

Alternatively, you can convert `response.text` to a dictionary using `json.loads`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in `df = pd.DataFrame(response)` response is not the right type of object you need as an argument. You need to give as argument a list of Dictionaries. You can parse the `response.text`