# How to extract text from nested list in python and put in column?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, nested-lists

This is the first observation. I need these all in different columns instead of the same column.

```
[{'route': 'Oral',
  'brand_name': 'MSK',
  'active_ingredients': [{'dose': {'denominator_unit': 'Unknown',
     'numerator': '1',
     'numerator_unit': 'Unknown',
     'denominator': '1'},
    'name': 'Diethylcarbamazine, Oxibendazole'}],
  'atc_vet_code': 'QP52AC57',
  'dosage_form': 'Tablet',
  'manufacturer': {'registration_number': 'USA-USFDACVM-N136483',
   'name': 'MSK'}}]
```

I want the result to look something like this.

| route | brand name | active_ingredients | brand name | atc_vet_code | dosage_form' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| oral | MSK | Diethylcarbamazine, Oxibendazole | QP52AC57 | tablet |  |

Comment: it seems the result output is not correct. `dosage_from` ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the answer here [Convert list of dictionaries to a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-pandas-dataframe)

The relevant answer is the one talking about `json_normalize`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53831756/381179

A list of nested dicts is pretty much what the json data format would look like, and rather than writing some custom read-in functionality, you can use what's already there

Comment: I have all this data inside a dataframe.