# How to make a Dataframe from dictionary and list of dictionary

Tags: python, json, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary like below, i want to create a a dataframe but only from result key(i.e a list of dictionary)

```
dict =  {
 'ID': 'c2a4da4e3',
 'Time': None,
 'recordsReturned': 5,
'TotalRecord': 512,
'result': '[{"Time":"2022-03-04T14:39:59.999Z","metric":"dpmo","value":15}, 
          {"Time":"022-03-04T14:39:59.999Z" ","metric":"Load Balancing","value":1}, 
         {"Time":"2022-03-04T14:39:59.999Z","metric":"High Defect","value":13},
          {"Time":"2022-03-04T14:39:59.999Z","metric":"Low Defect","value":121},
         {"Time":"2022-03-04T14:39:59.999Z","metric":"Successful ","value":306}]',
        'Token': None
  }
```

I want something like below.

```
df = Time                        metric           value
     2022-03-04T14:39:59.999Z     dpmo             15
     022-03-04T14:39:59.999Z      Load Balancing   1
```

i tried this but gives me an empty list of values

```
print(([key for key in raw.keys()][4], [value for value in raw.values()][4]))
```

Comment: Why do you expect that `print(...)` statement to create a dataframe?

Comment: Your `result` key is a _json string_, not a list of dictionaries. Sure, it _represents_ a list of dicts, but you still need to parse it into one before doing anything with it. Check out the docs for the `json` module. Do you see something there that can parse a json string to an object for you?

Comment: And once you have an actual list of dicts, a quick google search yields a stackoverflow link that answers your question. [Convert list of dictionaries to a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: print was just to test. i want to create a dataframe

Comment: i used this code to get the dict 
dict = json.loads(resp.text).......i believe its already parsed here

Comment: Okay, you parsed the `resp.text` to a dict. But the `result` key of that dict is _still a string, isn't it?_ Use the same `json.loads()` to convert that string to an actual list of dicts. Then see the question Ilinked.

Comment: hmm.ok got it. It works now. i used  result = json.loads(dict['result']) and created a dataframe df = pd.DataFrame(result). Gives me exactly what i want. Thanks