# Pandas: JSON Normalize with brackets around the JSON?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How might I use `json_normalize` to breakdown a nested JSON object that is contained in a list?

Consider this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'xd': [
    [{
        "status": "pass",
        "desc": "desc",
        "actionable": False,
        "err_code": "None",
        "err_msg": "None"
    }],
    [{
        "status": "fail",
        "desc": "desc",
        "actionable": True,
        "err_code": "None",
        "err_msg": "None"
    }] ]})


pd.json_normalize(df['xd'])  # not expected
```

Expected output:

```
  status  desc  actionable err_code err_msg
0   pass  desc       False     None    None
1   fail  desc        True     None    None
```

Comment: do you have any more dicts in the inner list?

Comment: No more dicts in the inner list in this example.

Comment: how about this: `pd.DataFrame(data['xd'][0])` where `data` is the dictionary whose key is "xd"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your json objects are under the **xd** columns, you can exctract that json, which is a list of dictionaries. A list of dictionaries can be used to create a dataframe object, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-pandas-dataframe).

```
list_of_dicts = list_of_dicts=list(map(lambda l: l[0], df['xd'].to_list()))
expected = pd.Dataframe(list_of_dicts)
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: No, consider the case where there are multiple rows; I have updated the example.

Comment: Ok, then the list of dict needs to be computed as follows
```list_of_dicts=list(map(lambda l: l[0], df['xd'].to_list()))```

Comment: ``pd.DataFrame([ent for ent in df.xd.str[0]])`` also works

Answer (score 1):

You could `explode` + `tolist` + DataFrame constructor:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(df['xd'].explode().tolist())
```

Output:

```
  status  desc  actionable err_code err_msg
0   pass  desc       False     None    None
1   fail  desc        True     None    None
```