# Nested Dict to DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to get the following dict into a specific DataFrame.

The dict is structured as follows :

```
test = {'JTTIX US Equity': 
            {'HB_ASSET_CLASS_ALLOCATION': 
                {'Equity': '32.14642',
                 'Debt': '60.890407'},
             'HB_MARKET_CAP_ALLOCATION': 
                {'Small-cap': '0.776239',
                 'Mid-cap': '10.81831',
                 'Large-cap': '88.027725'}}}
```

The final DataFrame that i am trying to reach is :

```
BBG_ID              FIELD                       TYPE                        VALUE
JTTIX US Equity     HB_ASSET_CLASS_ALLOCATION   Equity                      32.14642
JTTIX US Equity     HB_ASSET_CLASS_ALLOCATION   Debt                        60.890407
JTTIX US Equity     HB_MARKET_CAP_ALLOCATION    Small-cap                   0.776239
JTTIX US Equity     HB_MARKET_CAP_ALLOCATION    Mid-cap                     10.81831
JTTIX US Equity     HB_MARKET_CAP_ALLOCATION    Large-cap                   88.027725
```

I tried all the options on this nice answer here [Convert list of dictionaries to a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-pandas-dataframe), but i am still not able to reach the final format i want.

I think i can do it by creating a loop but want to double check if there is a way i can avoid it since the real dict is really big.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `stack`. Essentially construct the DataFrame, `stack` it; construct a DataFrame again, `stack` it again; then `reset_index`:

```py
tmp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test, orient='index').stack()
out = pd.DataFrame(tmp.tolist(), tmp.index).stack().rename_axis(index=['BBG_ID','FIELD','TYPE']).reset_index(name='VALUE')
```

Output:

```
            BBG_ID                      FIELD       TYPE      VALUE
0  JTTIX US Equity  HB_ASSET_CLASS_ALLOCATION     Equity   32.14642
1  JTTIX US Equity  HB_ASSET_CLASS_ALLOCATION       Debt  60.890407
2  JTTIX US Equity   HB_MARKET_CAP_ALLOCATION  Small-cap   0.776239
3  JTTIX US Equity   HB_MARKET_CAP_ALLOCATION    Mid-cap   10.81831
4  JTTIX US Equity   HB_MARKET_CAP_ALLOCATION  Large-cap  88.027725
```