# Parse a Text file to a table using Python or SQL

Tags: python, sql, parsing

I have a text file like this

```
{u'Product_id': u'1234567', u'Product_name': u'Apple', u'Product_code': u'2.4.14'}
{u'Product_id': u'1234123', u'Product_name': u'Orange', u'Product_code': u'2.4.20'}
```

I have searched it on google but not know yet what kind of string is this, it's not json . How to parse it to table using Python or SQL specifically PL/SQL ? Desired table result have column and row like this:

```
Product_id  Product_name    Product_code 
1234567     Apple           2.4.14
1234123     Orange          2.4.20
```

Comment: What kind of string ? That is python code, I don't get how you can have that in a text file

Comment: @azro just a txt file

Comment: Who created that file ? That is VERY bad idea to put python dict like that in a text file, this is nonsense

Comment: @azro this is not a dict or anything related to Python, just a txt file and I want to convert it to table

Comment: What you show is EXACTLY dicts with unicode string in it, that is **VALID** python code. So that isn't a machine-readable content, that isn't JSON or something, but code

Comment: @azro so first I need to clear all the 'u' stuff so it look like python dict

Comment: You don't , that just means unicode strings, that is still valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I must say that this method is not very healthy. In order for the code I wrote to work, the schema of the data in the txt should not change;

```
import ast

info = open('sample_file.txt')
exported = []
for row in info.readlines():
    exported.append(ast.literal_eval(row))
print(exported)
# output: 
# [{'Product_code': '2.4.14', 'Product_id': '1234567', 'Product_name': 'Apple'},
#  {'Product_code': '2.4.20', 'Product_id': '1234123', 'Product_name': 'Orange'}]
```

Comment: then Convert `list of dict` to Dataframe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-pandas-dataframe