# How to get Json-Keys as column-names in a CSV with pyson?

Tags: python, json, csv

I have the following code:

```
import requests
import pandas

api_url = "***"
Headers = { "Authorization" : "***" }
response = requests.get(api_url, headers=Headers)

obj = pandas.read_json(response.text, orient='values')
obj.to_csv('output1.csv')
```

And I get the follwing output in a CSV:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVdhR.png)

So the JSON-Keys are not the column names and everything is in Column A nothing in Column B and so on. How can I get the JSON-Keys as Column-Names?

```
df = pandas.json_normalize(response.json()["value"])
print(df)
```

looks like this:

```
 pullRequestId  codeReviewId  ... completionOptions.transitionWorkItems                                             labels
```

0            11885         11885  ...                                   NaN                                                NaN
1            11965         11965  ...                                   NaN                                                NaN
2            11958         11958  ...                                   NaN                                                NaN
3            11936         11936  ...                                   NaN                                                NaN
4            11923         11923  ...                                   NaN                                                NaN
..             ...           ...  ...                                   ...                                                ...
96           11220         11220  ...                                   NaN  [{'id': '1d85b8f2-7712-46e6-9eb0-dd789ed3d7d1'...
97           11122         11122  ...                                  True                                                NaN
98           11142         11142  ...                                   NaN  [{'id': '1d85b8f2-7712-46e6-9eb0-dd789ed3d7d1'...
99           11194         11194  ...                                  True                                                NaN
100          11201         11201  ...                                   NaN                                                NaN

[101 rows x 44 columns]

But the CSV looks like this with:

```
df.to_csv('output1.csv')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzcEU.png)

Comment: so does the original json object only have one key, `"value"`, with a value that's a list of dictionaries?  What does `json.loads(response.text)["value"][0]` look like?

Comment: @Joe I have edited the answer in the question.

Comment: So is `json.loads(response.text)["value"]` a list of dictionaries? If so, try [these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20638006/6394617) solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel is known to have an awful support for CSV files. Long story made short, it generally can only load correctly CSV files that have been produced by Excel on the same system. Specifically the separator is given by the system locale.

Here, I would assume that you have a system (probably West European) that uses a semicolon (`;`) as separator. The good news is that you can ask Pandas to use that separator with:

```
df.to_csv('output1.csv', sep=';')
```

If it still does not work, you will have to search in your system configuration which separator is expected, or alternatively build a minimal CSV file from your Excel system and read it in a text editor (notepad is enough) to see which separator is actually used.

Answer (score 0):

When importing JSON data into the Pandas DataFrame, you must set the orient parameter of pandas.read_json() correctly to use the keys in the JSON as column names. JSON data can be organized in different ways depending on how the data is structured. If you want to use your JSON data as column names, assume that your JSON data is structured as objects in a list. In this case, you need to set the orient parameter to "records". Here is an updated version of your code this way:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

api_url = "***"
headers = { "Authorization" : "***" }
response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)

df = pd.read_json(response.text, orient='records')

df.to_csv('output1.csv', index=False)
```

This script will convert your JSON data to "records", using the keys in JSON as column names. If your JSON data has a different structure or needs special handling, you can convert JSON data to DataFrame by setting the orient parameter appropriately.

Comment: With this code the csv looks like the first image I have posted in my question. It doesen`t work.