Python Pool.apply_async() is returning None type objects
I have a 4GB+ file in which each line represents a very nested JSON string. An example of what the file looks like would be below:
{"core":{"id":"1","field1":{"subfield1":1, "subfield2":{"subsubfield1": 1}},....,"field700":700}}
{"core":{"id":"1","field1":{"subfield1":1, "subfield2":{"subsubfield1": 1}},....,"field700":700}}
100,000+ lines like above

I need to do the followings:

convert each line in the file to JSON object
flatten each JSON object so that all the key-value pairs are on the same level while filtering only a few keys that I need (I need ~100 keys out of a total of 700+ in each JSON object)

My plan is to divide this 100K plus lines into multiple chunks, and use multiprocessing to flatten the JSON objects in each chunk and combine them back into a dataframe. Because I am new to multiprocessing, I read a few posts including this and this (and a few more). I tried to write my code based on the first post like this:
import json
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process, Queue

import pandas as pd


# list of ~100 columns I want to keep
COLS_TO_KEEP = {'id', 'field1', 'subfield1', 'subsubfield2', 'field8', ..., 'field680'}


def chunk_the_list(list_of_items, chunk_size):
    for i in range(0, len(list_of_items), chunk_size):
        yield list_of_items[i : i + chunk_size]


def do_work(list_of_dicts):
    results = []
    for d in list_of_dicts:
        results.append(flatten_dict(d))


def flatten_dict(d, parent_key="", sep="_"):
    # This function recursively dives into each JSON object and flattens them
    items = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        new_key = parent_key + sep + k if parent_key else k
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            items.extend(flatten_dict(v, new_key, sep=sep).items())
        else:
            if new_key in COLS_TO_KEEP:
                items.append((new_key, v))
    return dict(items)


def main():
    raw_data_file_path_name = 'path/to/file.txt' # file is 4GB+
    file = open(raw_data_file_path_name, encoding="utf-8").readlines()
    listify = [json.loads(line) for line in file]
    size_of_each_chunk = int(len(listify) / (multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 2))
    chunked_data = chunk_the_list(listify, size_of_each_chunk)

    p = Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 2)
    results = [p.apply_async(do_work, args=(chunk,)) for chunk in chunked_data]

    results = [item.get() for item in results] # This list has None type objects when I check using debugger
    results = sum(results, []) # because the above line returns None values, this step errors out 

    # I want to create a Pandas dataframe using the accumulated JSON/dictionary objects from results and write it out as a parquet or csv file at the end like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20638258/1330974
    df = pd.DataFrame(results)
    df.to_parquet('df.parquet.gzip', compression='gzip')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()
    main()

Am I doing something wrong to get None type objects back in the results set? Thank you in advance for suggestions and answers!

I'm not sure if this is the issue, but you have a typo. It should be ... p.apply_async(flatten_dict ... not ... p.apply_async(flatten_dicts ....

@Simon1 Thank you. I actually named do_work() as flatten_dicts() in my actual code, but I changed it to do_work() so that StackOverflow readers can better understand. But I forgot to update the code when I copied-pasted it. But yes, even with do_work(), it is still returning [None, None, None, None...] for results.

do_work() doesn't return anything. Try adding return results to the end of the function.

Ah...that's right! Thank you very much. Now it works! Please feel free to post your suggest as an answer and I will accept it. :) Thank you very much again!

You need to add a return statement to your do_work() function.
def do_work(list_of_dicts):
    results = []
    for d in list_of_dicts:
        results.append(flatten_dict(d))
    return results


1.Handling Multiprocessing Results
def do_work(list_of_dicts):
    results = []
    for d in list_of_dicts:
        results.append(flatten_dict(d))
    return results  # Add this line to return the results

2.Flattening JSON and Filtering Columns
3.Multiprocessing and Joining Results:
import json
import multiprocessing
import pandas as pd

# list of ~100 columns I want to keep
COLS_TO_KEEP = {'id', 'field1', 'subfield1', 'subsubfield2', 'field8', ..., 'field680'}

def chunk_the_list(list_of_items, chunk_size):
    for i in range(0, len(list_of_items), chunk_size):
        yield list_of_items[i : i + chunk_size]

def flatten_dict(d, parent_key="", sep="_"):
    # This function recursively dives into each JSON object and flattens them
    items = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        new_key = parent_key + sep + k if parent_key else k
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            items.extend(flatten_dict(v, new_key, sep=sep).items())
        else:
            if new_key in COLS_TO_KEEP:
                items.append((new_key, v))
    return dict(items)

def do_work(list_of_dicts):
    results = []
    for d in list_of_dicts:
        results.append(flatten_dict(d))
    return results

def main():
    raw_data_file_path_name = 'path/to/file.txt'  # file is 4GB+
    with open(raw_data_file_path_name, encoding="utf-8") as file:
        listify = [json.loads(line) for line in file]

    size_of_each_chunk = int(len(listify) / (multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 2))
    chunked_data = chunk_the_list(listify, size_of_each_chunk)

    p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 2)
    results = p.map(do_work, chunked_data)  # Use map for simplicity

    # Flatten the results list of lists into a single list
    flattened_results = [item for sublist in results for item in sublist]

    # Create Pandas DataFrame and save as Parquet file
    df = pd.DataFrame(flattened_results)
    df.to_parquet('df.parquet.gzip', compression='gzip')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Thank you. I accepted Simon's answer above because he commented about the missing return statement in do_work() before you posted your answer. :)
